# How to change connect_timeout in Azure MySQL

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, connect-timeout

I have Azure MySQL instance (managed instance) and I want to change connect_timeout in server options. 
When I in MySQL Workbench do

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'connect_timeout';
```

The result is 'connect_timeout', '10'
the same result I get if I connect to mysql instance via command line.

How I can change this option?
In Azure portal there is "Server parameters" and there is only 
wait_timeout 120 
interactive_timeout 28800

But there is no connect_timeout.

Also I've tried to do

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=30;
```

But got an error
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation

Thank you

Comment: according to the error, you are attempting to manipulate data with a restricted user

Comment: This is because it is Azure MySQL managed instance and I connect with user that was created and setted during starting the instance, but in Azure this user still does not have superuser privilleges, so it is expected that I am able to manage the setting from the Azure config portal, but I did not found connect_timeout there.

Comment: I tried to use Azure Cli but got
az mysql server configuration show --name connect_timeout --resource-group myresource --server staging

The configuration 'connect_timeout' does not exist for MySQL server version 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `wait_timeout` value on Azure > Your server > Server parameters.